# No sound under in IDE on Linux (OK in Jar)

Tags: linux, eclipse, audio, java

I use openjdk-1.6 on Linux platform (that's a requirement)
I need to play stream audio. Based on this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/PlayingStreamingSampledAudio.htm

I wrote something like this:

```
SourceDataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(....);
SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
line.open(stream.getFormat());
line.start();
```

But the problem is in line

```
line.open(stream.getFormat());
```

Used format is supported by the system.

I have `LineUnavailableException`.

But the problem is that I have this exception only under eclipse. When I create executable jar and run it - everything is OK - no exceptions.

As far as I understand from googling and some experiments - problem is in security restrictions. Executable jar runs under current user and has access to sound device, eclipse somehow not. I tried to add all system users to audio group, tried to run eclipse as root...  Nothing helped.

I'm not a guru in Linux and eclipse. Does anybody know how to solve this problem or at least how to change security restrictions for eclipse?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: *"problem is in security restrictions"*  Very unlikely.  *"I wrote something like this"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Add code to print out properties of the JRE that is running the code.  I suspect Eclipse uses a different VM than the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact example I have in code.

```
int sampleRate = 40000;
int sampleBits = 16;
SourceDataLine _line;           
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate,sampleBits,1,true, true);
SourceDataLine.Info info = new SourceDataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
_line  = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
_line.open(format);
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to my print of properties was considered as wrong code, here is a link with JRE properties list (under eclipse):
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ef4f8GvEprhWWrrA57B0p2w6h5qOio4Wjz0ycY9-_0Q/edit?usp=sharing

here using executable jar:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxbPIa4YUwURCdUZsCNL1Iehq--OT2eu35Q0QHKonEg/edit?usp=sharing

To be honest - didn't find any criminal differences...